# Time since golang nanosecond timestamp

Tags: go, time

**Q1.** How do I create a golang [time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) struct from a nanosecond timestamp?

**Q2.** How do I then compute the number of hours since this timestamp?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Go a "time" object is represented by a value of the struct type [`time.Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time).

You can create a `Time` from a nanosecond timestamp using the [`time.Unix(sec int64, nsec int64)`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) function where it is valid to pass `nsec` outside the range `[0, 999999999]`.

And you can use the [`time.Since(t Time)`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) function which returns the elapsed time since the specified time as a [`time.Duration`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) (which is basically the time difference in nanoseconds).

```
t := time.Unix(0, yourTimestamp)
elapsed := time.Since(t)
```

To get the elapsed time in hours, simply use the [`Duration.Hours()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Hours) method which returns the duration in hours as a floating point number:

```
fmt.Printf("Elapsed time: %.2f hours", elapsed.Hours())
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qtVhf4cNLM).

**Note:**

`Duration` can format itself intelligently in a format like `"72h3m0.5s"`, implemented in its [`String()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.String) method:

```
fmt.Printf("Elapsed time: %s", elapsed)
```

Comment: To save some googling, max time.UnixNano() is: `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807 +0000 UTC`

Answer (score 5):

You pass the nanoseconds to [`time.Unix(0, ts)`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix), example:

```
func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    ts := int64(1257856852039812612)
    timeFromTS := time.Unix(0, ts)
    diff := now.Sub(timeFromTS)
    fmt.Printf("now: %v\ntime from ts: %v\ndiff: %v\ndiff int: %v", now, timeFromTS, diff, int64(diff))
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://go.dev/play/p/A0apXDhLExa)